# How modify Facebook's Webview to maintain it correctly displayed on device screen?

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I'm developing a little Android application that connects to Facebook and shares some content. I would like to know if there's a way to modify the size (height and widht) of this default Facebook's webview, because it is a little high and because of that the top bar default of the application is being hide for it.

Is this possible?
I'm using the newest Facebook SDK for Android: 3.0

Thanks i advance.

EDIT: the webview is like this.
[image]

It should be like this, but like in my case, it's a little high and hiding part of app's top bar. For example, where is Facebook's name, the top of web view shows just half of it.

Comment: it's a little unclear if you are using the web site by a link or the FB's SDK.

Comment: I'm using the Facebook's SDK and I followed the sample on their site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/, the sixth step:  Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login

Comment: I don't understand, the webview is like this http://dragon.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-ash3/676411/303/375786482501892-/picker.png ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, but I can't post images yet. It is a little high, hiding part of the app top bar. Is there a way for resize it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a normal behavior from Facebook's API, by using the SDK for Android, because the samples availables have the same behavior. See SessionLoginSample on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

I think that's it. Hope it helps.

Thanks everyone for help too.